Recovery of grub (in EFI) after starting Windows 10 in dual boot
Well known problem, but unknown solution (at least so far). The question has been asked millions of times, but a solution to this specific case didn't show up while searching. Feel free to point me to an existing answer and mark this question as duplicate instead of writing a new one.
I installed Windows 10 in a new computer and then (in that order) OpenSUSE Leap 15.5. Just after the installation of Leap I got the OpenSUSE boot manager and booted into it with success. Then I wanted to finish up the installation of Windows and I started it. Note that I just started it and installed some drivers and some software (Thunderbird, VLC, Audacity, etc.). I didn't do any update (it may have done it behind my back, though).
Now when I boot I get thrown into the grub console with the few commands available and I'm not expert enough to know what to do there (1).
I inserted the OpenSUSE USB and booted from that, then at the menu I selected "rescue system". After loading all it has to load, I got into a root console and started trying to mount the directories of the installed Leap into /mnt in order to chroot into it (following the instructions in this answer). It is worth mentioning that the / partition in Leap is in a btrfs file system, if that makes any difference.
When I get to chroot /mnt I get the error "Bus error (core dumped)". I have no idea what that could mean and how to fix it.
I tried, following the instruction in the answer here, to directly tell grub2-install where to install grub, trying both with the efi partition mounted into /mnt/boot/efi and directly into the /dev/nvme0n1p4 device. None of them works. I get in both cases the error "grub2-install: error: failed to get canonical path for 'tmpfs' ". Notice that in the rescue Leap there is no update-grub command.
(1) While I was writing this question, this other popped up among the suggestions and I did try the commands shown there while in the grub prompt (obviously adapted to my system). They didn't work either: I still get thrown into the grub console without getting any menu with any choice.
If I select the Windows boot from the boot-order in the UEFI, Windows boots fine. I'm very out of ideas.
While I had the /boot/efi partition mounted, I noticed that in there there are the directories EFI, System Volume Information and some other stuff I forgot, as well as the file BackupSbb.bin. This leads me to believe that Windows did it's own stuff in the efi-partition, which leads me to the next, and possibly most important, question: is there anything the world can do to protect itself from the despotism of Microsoft (read, to prevent it from happening every time)?

SuSe is not beginner friendly in this situation, Ubuntu is. Commands and methods to reinstall Grub of the latter do no necessarily translate to the former. What options do you have in UEFI Boot menu, besides Windows bootloader manager? (BTW, BIOS isn't used since 2012)

And considering you installed Linux after Windows didn't Windows appear also in the Grub menu? If not then likely you installed SuSe in Legacy ("BIOS") mode, an unfortunate and sadly typical mistake. That being the case then 1. Make sure you disable Legacy/CSM mode in UEFI as that will assure the SuSe media boot and installs in the correct UEFI mode. Then simply reinstall by reusing the existing partitions making sure to select as EFI (ESP) the EFI partitions (don't format) alongside all the others used by SuSe (and previously created).

@ChanganAuto I wrote BIOS but I obviously mentioned UEFI Boot menu. SUSE did appear there and it is installed as UEFI, not legacy. In UEFI Boot menu I have the options: OpenSUSE, Windows Bootloader Manager and the USB stick, if I have inserted one. I thought about reinstalling, but I figured the next time I fire up Windows it will happen again and I don't want to spend my life reinstalling SUSE. I was looking for a more definitive solution, other than installing Windows in a virtual machine, which is a possibility, of course.

Whatever happened has nothing to do with Windows. I have many dual-boots and the advantage of UEFI mode is that bootloaders co-exist. Worst case scenario, after those major Windows feature updates, it changes the boot order to itself - somehow "convenient" because those tend to need one or more reboots - something that can be easily reversed by select the Linux bootloader again as 1st priority in UEFI. If the SuSe entry doesn't work something other happened.

@ChanganAuto OK, any idea as to what the "something other" could be?

Not Windows for sure.
